# Ionic + Angular: Auth0 JWT not sending token on headers

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jwt

I'm working on my first Ionic application and already made the authentication part.

But after authenticating, when I do a request using HttpClientModule, it does't have the token on the header and I get 401 from my API made in .net Core.

I've read a lot of post about this topic but no solution seems to fix the problem.

I don't think the problem is in the API because it's works on postman if you have the bearer token on headers.

This is my app.module.ts configuration:

```
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


import { IonicStorageModule, Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export function getAuthScheme(request) {
  return 'Bearer ';
}

export function jwtOptionsFactory(storage) {
  return {
      tokenGetter: () => {
      return storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    },
    authScheme: getAuthScheme,
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:44326', 'https://localhost:44326', 'https://localhost:44326/', 'localhost']
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [Storage],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I dint checked the use cordova option when creating the app. Maybe it has something to do with it?

---

UPDATE:
So, I've implemented an interceptor like Ronny said but the authorization header still don't appear.

app.mmodule.ts is like before but with this providers:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptorProvider, multi: true },
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
  ],
```

and this is my interceptor class:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class JwtInterceptorProvider implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    console.log(`Hello from JwtInterceptor`);
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((token) => {
      if (token) {
        const clonedRequest = this.addToken(request, token);
        return next.handle(clonedRequest);
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: any) {

    if (token) {

      console.log(`*******************************************************`);
      console.log(`Bearer ${token}`);

      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      };
      if (request.responseType === 'json') {
        console.log('Json request.');
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      }

      console.log('Header added.');

      console.log(`*******************************************************`);
      return request;

    }

  }

}
```

It says in the console 'Header added.' so its reaching the code. But the header don't show up on the final request. I feel like something in the app is overwriting the headers after this.
I'm really confused right now. I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the token to each request. Create an interceptor, validate that the user has a token, and added it to the request. This is an example:

```
// JWT interceptor
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';


@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    const currentAuthToken = this.authenticationService.currentAuthTokenValue;
    if (currentAuthToken && currentAuthToken.token) {
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${currentAuthToken.token}`,
        };
        if (request.responseType === 'json') {
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        }
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: headers
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

You need an authentication service to manage your user data. In this example, a behavior subject is used for that. Refer to this link for more info: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've implemented the interceptor as you said and checked all the thing on the example tutorial. But the Authorization still dont appear on the headers. I'm really confused here. I'm updating the code on the original post.

Comment: I think you are missing this line: 

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: headers
        });

That is where the header is added to the request.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
The problem was here:

`this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN').then(...)`

The interceptor was ignoring this promise and returning the request before the .get() was finished to add the header.

I just stored the token in my authentication class so I have it in memory.
I guess making the Interceptor wait for the .get() should work to.